# How to install a new beamer theme on linux (texlive and texmaker)

Tags: beamer, texlive, texmaker

I have a LaTeX Beamer template from this webpage (automatically download from university homepage): http://kom.aau.dk/~jkn/latex/files/AAUsimple_v1.2.1.zip

But I don't know how to use it. I could copy this into a new folder:

1. the 4 files from "local"
2. the folder "AAUgraphics"
3. the document "AAUsimpletheme.tex"

And then I could work in "AAUsimpletheme.tex". But it would be nice if I could make a new texfile and just load the theme with `usetheme`. How to do that? I just want to write a LaTeX-file in another folder and don't want to copy all the files every time I want to make a LaTeX Beamer project. And I have seen the instructions in the PDF (from the template) and I don't understand it.

It would be very nice if anyone could tell me how to install the template so I just have to use `\ustheme{AAUsimple}`. And please with an minimal `.tex` example.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, first I would be nice to know exactly which TeX Live you are using. I do not remember if the Ubuntu TeX Live actually create a texmf-local folder. So we start with this command

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

Let us assume it gives you a resonable result. I get `/opt/texlive/2013/../texmf-local` aka `/opt/texlive/2013/texmf-local`.

In the ZIP you mention, we need the `global` folder. Copy the contents of that into the found `texmf-local` folder. More or less

```
cp -r PATH/global/* OTHER-PATH/texmf-local/
```

The data in the `global` folder is already in TDS format.

We'd like to do a bit extra though:

1. Goto `OTHER-PATH/texmf-local/tex/latex/` rename `beamer` to `beamer-aau`, such that is very clear that this is the AAU files for beamer.
2. Go to the new `beamer-aau` folder. Create the subfolder `graphics`
3. Copy the contents of the `AAUgraphics` folder in the ZIP into this folder
4. Go back to your root dir and run `texhash` to redo the hash files.

BTW: for some of these commands you may need to add `sudo` depending on your installation.

You can now test it via

1. `kpsewhich beamercolorthemeAAUsimple.sty aau_logo_new.pdf`, if this returns to reasonable paths, then you have globally installed the theme on your computer.

Might be an idea to ask the AAU people to provide a HOWTO for the above. I provide a lengthy one for the installation of the AU letter class. All steps included for Windows (TL and MikTeX), Linux and Mac separately.